# ShouldSerialize is not working in ASP.Net Web Api oData

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to use public bool ShouldSerialize{MemberName}() { return false; } in ASP.Net Web API oData application with no luck. While when I am trying to serialize the class manually using Json.net, it works fine.

Do I miss any configuration in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but I had the same problem, so decided to answer.

The ODataMediaTypeFormatter does not use Json.NET out of the box like the JsonMediaTypeFormatter does.